# ¿Cuál es la forma más eficiente de detectar el soporte de un elemento en el navegador?

Tags: javascript

En muchos lados de internet, observo la forma de cómo consultar al navegador el soporte de un elemento para javascript. Por ejemplo:

```
var WebGL3DSupported = !!window.WebGLRenderingContext;
var WebGL3dSupported = 'WebGLRenderingContext' in window;
```

Sé que hay una tercera forma más certera de detectar el soporte de un elemento, que es a través de una función `var WebGL3dSupported = (function(){ //code })();`, pero...

¿Cuál de estas 2 formas es más eficiente para consultar al navegador el soporte de un elemento?

```
var microdata = !!document.getItems;
            o
var microdata = 'getItems' in document;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar el operador **not** es la repuesta.

---

#### Explicación:

De las 2 primeras formas mencionadas, he realizado pruebas y estos son los resultados para un bucle de 1000 iteraciones, tomando en cuenta que mi código es el siguiente:

#### Código:

```
function intest () {
    var WebGL3dSupported = 'WebGLRenderingContext' in window;
}

function nottest () {
    var WebGL3DSupported = !!window.WebGLRenderingContext;
}

var iterations = 10000;

console.time('in');
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    intest();
};
console.timeEnd('in');

console.time('not');
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    nottest();
};
console.timeEnd('not');
```

#### Resultado (menor es mejor):

[image: Desempeño JavaScript en validación de elemento]
[image: Tabla de valores con promedio]

---

Después de ver esos resultados, decidí incrementar las iteraciones a 10,000. El resultado fue el siguiente (en tiempo y uso de CPU):

Tiempo:

[image: Resultado en consola]

CPU:

[image: Uso de CPU]

Con base a ello, yo elegiría **not** y podrías mejorar con algo como lo siguiente:

```
function WebGL3DSupported () {
    return !!window.WebGLRenderingContext && WebGLRenderingContext.hasOwnProperty('prototype');
}
```

Comment: Te ganaste el premio Novell :D  Se confirmó la duda. Para agregar a la función:  function WebGL3DSupported () {
   var e = document.createElement('canvas');
      return !!window.WebGLRenderingContext && WebGLRenderingContext.hasOwnProperty('prototype') && ( e.getContext("webgl")  !== 'undefined' || e.getContext('experimental-webgl') !== 'undefined' ) ;
  }

Comment: @JamesPeter :D Gracias por el entusiasmo, me alegra que te haya funcionado. Si te convence puedes elegirla como "mejor respuesta" marcando la palomita.

Answer (score 3):

Básicamente es una pregunta difícil de contestar, pero es mas rápido usar `!!`.Por eso lo veras mas a menudo. [Acá esta el test](http://jsperf.com/notnot-vs-in/2). Aunque algunos desarrolladores están en desacuerdo porque es difícil de leer.

Una breve explicación seria:

El `var microdata = !!document.getItems;` conocido como *Not Not* es considerado una forma oscura de obligar un objeto a que sea casteado como boleano. El sera falso si no consigue nada, de lo contrario dejalo verdadero.

Mientras  `var microdata = 'getItems' in document;` solo busca si existe la propiedad del objeto y devuelve un valor boleano.

Aunque ambos hacen los mismo y hay una diferencia en el perfomance el `!!` es mucho mas rápido. Si quieres que tu código sea mas rápido úsalo, sino (quieres que se lea mejor) usa el `in`.

Comment: Gracias @Wilfredo P . En efecto, Not Not parece ser más eficiente que in. He realizado algunos test con diferentes versiones de navegador, donde solo Safari 9 hace una gran diferencia entre ambos. Algunos parecen ser lo contrario o casi empates.

Pero se nota que Not Not es más efectiva consultando en document. Ahora preguntado en window, no sé; debe ser igual.